# filterString done in a Queryparameters map . How to access different keys?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm am encountering this bug in my code (Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>?'). For the Uri.https(), I'm using a variable that contains a map with the queryParameters, these being the authToken, creatorId and the userId. If anyone can give me a tip, I would much appreciate it.

```
    Future fetchAndSetProducts([bool filterByUser = false]) async { 
        final _params = <String, String>{ 
         'auth': authToken, 
         'orderBy': json.encode("creatorId"), 
         'equalTo': json.encode(userId), 
     }; 
        final filterString = filterByUser ? _params : _params['auth']; 
        var url = Uri.https('https://demo1-102d7-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app', '/products.json', filterString);
```

Comment: you are passing `authToken` as a last param in `Uri.https` constructor - this is a `String` not a `Map`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.